# Setting up Cross Compilation for my SBT Auto plugin project

Tags: scala, sbt

I am writing a SBT Auto Plugin. This is my build.sbt file

```
lazy val foo = (project in file(".")).settings(
   name := "foo",
   sbtPlugin := true,
   organization := "com.foo",
   crossScalaVersions = Seq("2.11.8", "2.12.4")
)
```

but I get the error

```
overloaded method value settings with alternatives:
  (ss: sbt.Def.SettingsDefinition*)sbt.Project <and>
  => Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]]
 cannot be applied to (sbt.Def.Setting[String], sbt.Def.Setting[Boolean], sbt.Def.Setting[String], crossScalaVersions: Seq[String])
lazy val foo = (project in file(".")).settings(
                                                         ^
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i
```

My objective is that when I do `sbt publish` I publish two jar files. one for scala 2.11 and other for scala 2.12

Comment: `crossScalaVersions =` => `crossScalaVersions :=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to give it like `crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.8", "2.12.4")` instead of `crossScalaVersions = Seq("2.11.8", "2.12.4")`.

You can see more here [Cross-Building a Project](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build.html#cross-building-a-project).